# Order of template fields in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, filebeat

I have the template that ordered in this way
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vmLJf.jpg)

Is it possible to have it in the following order?

1. DateCreate
2. TransactionRequest
3. Events
4. Exceptions
5. TransactionResponse
6. IsExpired
7. IsFinished

I appreciate your answers!

Comment: To understand your needs. you want to arganise your data in this order in your document ?

Comment: Yes, I want to organize in this order

Comment: You can create mapping in this order, but why, organize your data in your doc have no real importance. If you want to got is in this order in your query, or in a view you can. No matter how the data is stocked in the DB

Comment: Could you help how to get it in this order in my query? Or if you know how to create mapping in this order, help please) I tried to create mapping using HTTP requests, kibana but always it was changed by elastic.

Comment: My bad, after few tests, it does not look to be possible. You will have to do it in your view or in your code